# MYSQL Date field always outputs 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've got a problem with inserting a birthday to a Date field in my database. 
it always returns 0000-00-00 when i check the date that was stored in the database.

I use the followin code:

```
$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['registration_dob_year']."/".$_POST['registration_dob_month']."/".$_POST['registration_dob_day']));
```

I know for a fact that my `$_POST['registration_dob_year']`, `$_POST['registration_dob_month']` and `$_POST['registration_dob_day']` variables are correct, because if i use the following code

```
echo $dob;
```

It prints something like `1986-01-07` on my page.

Comment: `05-01-1989` is not a valid DATETIME value. MySQL expects `YYYY-MM-DD`... however, the code you show above should output that. Can you verify what is *actually* shown?

Comment: i know, i just mistyped the output.corrected it

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 "Can you post a query?" - what do you mean by that? if you mean if my registration script actually queries to mysql, and stores all other data in my database, yes. it works correctly.

Comment: Why the heck are you using `str_replace()` on a concatenated string!! Sorry, but I'm sending that to [CSI:PHP](http://csiphp.com/blog/)

Comment: I have to wonder why you're replacing `/` with `-` when you could just construct the string using `-` to begin with.

Comment: @Jason McCreary yeah, i read that somewhere here on SO. i guess i kinda forgot to remove it after i concentrated the string, using ."/". instead of ."-". between my variables. it doesn't actually matter if i remove it, since the output will be the same.

Comment: @Gabi Barrientos, sure same output. But I'm still piecing together the exploded brain matter from viewing that :)

Comment: @Jason McCreary well, as i started out my code wasn't this messy. i just added some stuff from 'solutions' i found, and i figured that i'd clean up after i got it to work correctly. sorry for the brain matter everywhere.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using to insert the date into the database?

Comment: @EvanMulawski sure, here you go: 
$sql = "insert into user_data (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_email, user_paypal, user_country, user_main_ip, user_security_question_1, user_security_question_2, user_security_answer_1, user_security_answer_2, user_activationcode, user_activated, user_rank, user_joindate, user_dob)values(NULL, '$username', '$password', '$email', '$paypal', '$country', '$ip', '$security_question_1', '$security_question_2', '$security_answer_1', '$security_answer_2', '$activationcode', '0', '1', NULL, '$dob')";

Comment: @GabiBarrientos I mean can I see the insert query that is actually supposed to be putting these things into the db? It's likely that the problem is there, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you complicating things? Just use:

```
$dob = $_POST['registration_dob_year']."-".$_POST['registration_dob_month']."-".$_POST['registration_dob_day'];
```